# How to make Browser load css and js file from cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

My MVC website is too slow because the browser always reload all css and js files from the server instead of using cache. So how can I do that?

My slow website:
[image]

My faster website:

[image]

> Update 1: I found these settings in the HttpResponse, how can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: You maybe want to make a PWA. You should check "service workers" which lets you cache some files even when te user is offline.

Comment: Seems that you have some cache busting technique in place (as in this example [link](https://madskristensen.net/blog/cache-busting-in-aspnet/)). The server is adding the parameter v=<random number> to your files URLs, which tricks the browser into downloading the file again, since it doesn't have the same URL as previous requests.

Comment: how do you add these resources to the page? are you using bundles?

Comment: Hi Sanfalero and Derloopkat, I used @RenderSection("Styles", false) to add these resources to the page, and they don't have "v=<random number>" in the URLs. The reason is that there is "Cache-Control:no-cache" in the HttpResponse. Please take a look in my Update1